# Why am I getting this error message when searching for a library?

Tags: libraries, sdl

I'm trying to install a custom Mightex software and at some point I get the following error message:

```
configure: error: Cannot find required SDL library.
```

So after googling I found [this page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=sdl2)

I typed:

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl2-2.0-0
```

but the error persisted after the installation and now I'm at a loss.. Any ideas?

*EDIT*:

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04

After recommendations I also installed `libsdl2-dev` but that didn't change anything. My output from running `ld -lSDL --verbose` is [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9564435/). Unfortunately I can give limited information about the software I'm trying to install as it's proprietary.

Comment: I think you need the developer library instead `libsdl2-dev`. Try installing that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

Comment: that's not what I'm asking... that questions is with regards to using .tar.gz which I don't want to do

Comment: @Lucio I tried that but it still didn't work..

Comment: What software are you trying to install? Does it happen with any package? What OS do you have? A screenshoot may help.

Comment: I added some info to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the package that needed to be installed is `libsdl1.2-dev`.

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2-dev
```